# Lista enlazada carga valores a veces

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un programa con un menu para cargar , eliminar y visualizar una lista enlazada atraves de la clase lista y nodo. El problema es que a veces se cargan todos los valores normalmente , y otras el programa crashea depues de cargar uno o dos valores.Si intento crear una lista y la cargo fuera del do while del menú, el programa solo carga 17 elementos. Si intento cargar uno mas, el programa se cierra.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "Nodo.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Lista.h"

using namespace std;

void menu(){
  cout<<"1: Ingresar cliente "<<endl;
  cout<<"2: Eliminar cliente "<<endl;
  cout<<"3: Visualizar clientes "<<endl;
  cout<<"4: Salir "<<endl;
}

int main(){
  Lista <string> l;
  string name;
  int op,pos;

  do{
    menu();
    cin >> op;

    switch(op){

      case 1:

        cout<<"Ingrese Nombre\n";
        cin>>name;
        l.insertValue(name);
        break;     

      case 2:

        cout<<"Ingrese cliente a eliminar\n";
        cin>>pos;
        l.deleteAt(pos);
        break;   

      case 3:

        l.printList();
    }

    system("pause");      
    system("cls");  

  }while(op!=4);

  Lista <string> l1;
  return 0;
}
```

Lista.h

```
    #include "Nodo.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #ifndef  _LISTA_H
    #define  _LISTA_H

    using namespace std;

    template <class T> class Lista{

      protected:

        T dato;
        Nodo<T>* lista;

      public:

        Lista(){
          lista=0;
        }

        void deleteAt(int p){
          Nodo<T>* temp = lista;

          if(p==1){
            lista=lista->obtenerEnlace();
            free(temp);
          }
          else{
            for(int i =0;i<p-2;i++) temp=temp->obtenerEnlace();

            Nodo<T>* temp2 =temp->obtenerEnlace();
            temp->ponerEnlace(temp2->obtenerEnlace());
            free(temp2);
          }
        }

        void insertValue(T d){
          Nodo<T> * nuevo =(Nodo<T>*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo<T>));
          nuevo->ponerDato(d);
          nuevo->ponerEnlace(lista);
          lista=nuevo;
        }        

        void printList(){
          Nodo<T> * temp =lista;

          while(temp!=0){
            cout<<temp->obtenerDato()<<endl;
            temp=temp->obtenerEnlace();               
          }
        }
    };

    #endif
```

Nodo.h

```
#ifndef _NODO_H 
#define _NODO_H


template <class T> class Nodo{

    protected:

    T dato;
    Nodo<T> * enlace;

    public:


    Nodo(T d){

        enlace=0;
        dato=d;

    }    


    Nodo(T d,Nodo * n){

        enlace=n;
        dato=d;

    }    


    Nodo<T>* obtenerEnlace() const{

        return enlace;     

    }


    void ponerEnlace(Nodo * n){

        enlace=n;   

    }

    void ponerDato(T d){

        dato=d;   

    }


    T obtenerDato() const{

        return dato;   

    }


};


#endif
```

Comment: intenta agregando el `break` en el `case 3:`...

Comment: Falta la implementación de `Nodo`. Lo que indicas como `Nodo.h` es realmente `Lista.h`

Answer (score 1):

```
void deleteAt(int p){
  Nodo<T>* temp = lista;

  if(p==1){
    lista=lista->obtenerEnlace();
    free(temp);
  }
  else{
    for(int i =0;i<p-2;i++) temp=temp->obtenerEnlace();

    Nodo<T>* temp2 =temp->obtenerEnlace();
    temp->ponerEnlace(temp2->obtenerEnlace());
    free(temp2);
  }
}
```

Supongamos que no hay elementos en la lista... ¿Qué sucederá si llamo a esta función? Intentará acceder a memoria no reservada y eso no mola... menos aún si además intenta liberarla.

```
void deleteAt(int p){
  if( lista == 0 ) return;
  // ...
}
```

En C++ los índices empiezan en 0. Que tu función trate el primer elemento de la lista con el índice 1 es contrario a la norma común y es propenso a dar errores. Lo correcto sería poner:

```
if(p==0){
  lista=lista->obtenerEnlace();
  free(temp);
}
```

El obligar a que el primer índice sea 0 te obliga a hacer algorítmica rara:

```
for(int i =0;i<p-2;i++) temp=temp->obtenerEnlace();
```

¿No sería más sencillo hacer esto?

```
while( p-- ) temp = temp->obtenerEnlace();
```

Aunque ya puestos a prevenir que nos salgamos de la lista:

```
while( p-- && temp ) temp = temp->obtenerEnlace();
```

Si analizamos otros posibles problemas podemos fijarnos en `temp2`

```
Nodo<T>* temp2 = temp->obtenerEnlace();
```

¿Qué sucede si `temp` o `temp2` apunta a 0? Fácil, la aplicación volverá a cascar.

```
while( p-- && temp ) temp = temp->obtenerEnlace();

if( temp )
{
  Nodo<T>* temp2 = temp->obtenerEnlace();
  if( temp2 )
    temp->ponerEnlace(temp2->obtenerEnlace());

  free(temp2);
}
```

Se que son muchas comprobaciones, pero es el precio a pagar por trabajar con memoria dinámica.

No garantizo que esto solucione tu problema, ya que no has proporcionado un ejemplo mínimo compilable, pero ten por seguro que tu código es bastante inseguro.

---

Esto me despistó porque al principio estaba etiquetada la pregunta como C...

```
void insertValue(T d){
  Nodo<T> * nuevo =(Nodo<T>*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo<T>));
  nuevo->ponerDato(d);
  nuevo->ponerEnlace(lista);
  lista=nuevo;
}
```

En C++ los objetos hay que crearlos con `new` y borrarlos con `delete`. `malloc` y `free` sirven para reservar o liberar memoria... Pero no llamarán al constructor ni al destructor. Lo correcto sería hacer:

```
void insertValue(T d){
  Nodo<T> * nuevo = New Nodo<T>(d);
  nuevo->ponerEnlace(lista);
  lista=nuevo;
}
```

Y sustituir esto:

```
free(temp2);
```

Por esto:

```
delete temp2;
```

Comment: Gracias por las correciones!! el problema parece estar al insertar nodos...

Comment: Cree una lista por fuera del menú y llega a cargar 17 elemntos en la lista...luego el programa se cierra :(..

Comment: @Juan ¿Podrías confirmarme si la edición de mi respuesta soluciona tu problema?

Comment: No... el problema se solcionó al limpiar el buffer luego de cada cin.

Comment: Eso te está pasando entonces por mezclar `cin` y `cout` con `system`

Comment: @Juan no puedo editar el comentario porque  estoy desde un móvil. revisa mi comentario anterior

Answer (score 1):

No existe ningún error en tu código que lleve a ese comportamiento, a pesar de ser muy poco o nada robusto.

El error se da al mezclar métodos de entrada/salida, y en concreto, mezclar `std::cin` y `std::cout` con `printf` y `scanf`.

¿Y dónde has puesto un printf/puts/etc? Precisamente en la llamada a `system` (de manera implícita).

Si mezclas métodos, efectivamente debes limpiar o vaciar los buffers (en realidad, sincronizar). Ten en cuenta, además, que en algunas ocasiones los buffers pueden haberse sincronizado implícitamente. Por ejemplo, cuando se utiliza el objeto `std::endl`, en una instrucción del tipo `std::cout << std::endl;`, el buffer del objeto `std::cout` se sincronizará automáticamente, es decir, internamente, se hará una llamada a `std::cout.flush()`, por lo que no necesitarías añadir esa sentencia explícitamente antes de cambiar a `printf`, por ejemplo.

Finalmente, y aunque no sea parte de la pregunta, te responderé a varias cuestiones que han surgido al ver tu código.

1. Aunque en C, C++ y otros lenguajes de programación los índices se controlen de 0 a n-1 en un tipo de datos indizado, como comenta eferion, no significa que no puedas crear una clase cuyos índices vayan de 1 a n. Eso es **totalmente válido**, aunque yo no te lo aconsejaría.
2. Estás **mezclando C con C++**, y eso puede llevar a errores graves. Por ejemplo, estás creando objetos con `malloc`, y (tal y como comenta eferion también), esto produce que no se llame al constructor de la clase. En C++ los objetos se crean con `new` y se destruyen con `delete`, que llama al destructor definido en la clase (o al destructor por defecto).
3. No utilizas los **constructores** de tus clases para reservar memoria dinámica (relacionado con lo anterior), pero lo peor es que no la liberas mediante **destructores** (has puesto un `free` que resulta insuficiente). El resultado es que tras la creación de una lista, el programa inevitablemente tendrá *memory leaks* o **fugas de memoria**. Te recomiendo utilizar la herramienta `valgrind` para comprobar esto.
4. Crea siempre destructores para todas las clases que definas, pues si las instancias con `new`, deberás liberar sus objetos con `delete`. Si declaras objetos **estáticos** (sin punteros), como en la sentencia `Lista<std::string> lista;`, las llamadas a los destructores de las clases se harán **implícitamente**, es decir, aunque no veas la llamada en tu código, esta se realizará al final del ciclo de vida del objeto.
5. Aunque es correcto manejar los punteros utilizando literales como 0 (el puntero nulo), existen **convenciones** de nombres. Utiliza la constante `NULL` de la cabecera `cstdlib` para ello, o bien la palabra reservada `nullptr` (C++ 11), ya que ambas hacen referencia al puntero nulo.
6. Revisa los nombres de las **bibliotecas** que utilices. En concreto, en C++ existe una biblioteca estándar para cada una de las de C, pero cuyo nombre varía ligermanete (se añade una `c` al principio y se elimina el `.h`). La biblioteca `string.h` de C se correspondería con la biblioteca `cstring` de C++.
7. Como manejas cadenas a través de la clase `std::string`, y no haces nada complejo con ellas, no te hace falta la biblioteca `cstring`, que maneja las cadenas del tipo `char *`. En su lugar, la biblioteca que maneja cadenas de C++ (`std::string`) es la biblioteca `string` (no lleva la `c`, lo que indica que no tiene que ver con C, es sólo de C++).
8. Finalmente, te recomiendo revisar tu código, pues es muy **inseguro** y puede llevar a errores en tiempo de ejecución. Por ejemplo, en la función `deleteAt(int p)`, deberías en primer lugar comprobar que el índice está dentro de los límites que has definido (de 1 a n, o bien de 0 a n - 1). Por tanto, revisa tus conocimientos sobre **excepciones** en C++.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te sirva de ayuda para mejorar la calidad de tu código (lo digo sin acritud).

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con lo de que haya que crear destructores **siempre** ya que el compilador sabe crear un destructor por defecto que sirve en muchísimas ocasiones (aplicable también para el constructor por defecto y el constructor copia). Solo es necesario implementar uno propio cuando se gestiona memoria dinámica de forma manual o cuando el destructor debe hacer operaciones adicionales no contempladas (por ejemplo llamar a un log, avisar a otro proceso, cosas así...)

Comment: @eferion tienes toda la razón sobre los constructores y destructores por defecto. Sin embargo, creo que es una buena práctica y que no hace daño crear un destructor vacío explícitamente, sobre todo al principio. Por supuesto, cuando tienes experiencia y sabes lo que haces, no hace falta para nada.